# How to hide option in drop down menu?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to hide the "Select Value" option in the drop down menu of a plugin I have for my wordpress, I've tried the following code:

```
div.calc-drop-down-box.calc_dropDown_field_id_0 {
    
            visibility: hidden !important;

}
```

But this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all - please don't send us to external sites to reproduce the problem. A proper [mre] of your issue, belongs directly inside the question.

Comment: Second - you are only selecting the div element that contains the select element. Hiding that, is of course something completely different, than hiding just one of the options inside the select.

Comment: And `visibility: hidden` will not work to hide an option inside a select; use `display: none` instead.

Comment: Have you used your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see what the code actually is? It is likely to be an HTML select element with associated option elements so I don't understand why you are specifying a div.

Comment: I removed the "div" and changed it to display: none, but still didn't work. I'm not a coder at all, obviously - thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.calc-drop-down.ccb-appearance-field.ccb-field option:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

It gets the first child of type 'option' and hides it from the dropdown
https://jsfiddle.net/shn5dcmu/1/

Comment: Hey, I did notice that it's still displaying on mobile - but on desktop it's fine, do you know how I could hide this on mobile as well?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the jQuery click() method in combination with the on() method to hide the dropdown menu when the user click outside of the trigger element.

here is the  example code

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Hide Dropdown on Click Outside</title>
<style>
    ul{
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }
    ul li{
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 21px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    ul li a{
        display: block;
        padding: 8px 25px;
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    ul li a:hover{
        color: #fff;
        background: #939393;
    }
    ul li ul.dropdown-menu{
        min-width: 100%; /* Set width of the dropdown */
        background: #f2f2f2;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        left: 0;
    }
    ul li ul.dropdown-menu li{
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Show hide popover
        $(".dropdown").click(function(){
            $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").slideToggle("fast");
        });
    });
    $(document).on("click", function(event){
        var $trigger = $(".dropdown");
        if($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length){
            $(".dropdown-menu").slideUp("fast");
        }            
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Products ▾</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```